# EMStagePatches_$ORACLE_SID is using up space

Tags: oracle-11g, disk-space, enterprise-manager

We have this directory:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/EMStagePatches_$ORACLE_SID
```

We are running out of space and this directory is using up a lot of space. Is it safe to delete it? I think it is something to do with the Enterprise Manager patches. How can I stop Enterprise Manager from downloading stuff into that directory?

We are using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6 running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure this is not used by your OEM 
- rename the folder to `$ORACLE_HOME/EMStagePatches2_$ORACLE_SID` and restart your OEM if nothing bad happens i think is fine ti assume that is just a staging folder for the uploaded patches